# Convert DWORD to float and float to DWORD

Tags: c#

I got the conversion result from float to DWORD like below.

```
float f = 2.4f;
Uint32 value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0:D}", value); // 1075419546
```

And I would like to get conversion from DWORD,1075419546  to float,2.4f.
How can I get this?

Comment: There is the non-CLS-compliant [`SingleToUInt32Bits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletouint32bits?view=net-7.0#system-bitconverter-singletouint32bits(system-single)). I assume you cannot use that?

Comment: Hi. The DWORD is a 32bits unsigned integer and the float is 16 bits. You need a union. You can use shifting in order to save both parts of the DWORD. You will need 2 floats or to discard half of the DWORD. https://www.se.com/eg/en/faqs/FAQ000219304/

Comment: How about [`SingleToInt32Bits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletoint32bits?view=net-7.0#system-bitconverter-singletoint32bits(system-single))?

Comment: @CFCBazarcom Wait what? A C# float is an IEEE 754 single precision number, ie 32 bits. Also, they definitely don't need a union, which is great because they don't exist in C#.

Comment: Yes in C# a float is 32bits. There are equivalents to a union. https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c-/129657-convert-dword-hex-float.html

Comment: Maybe something like this:      DWORD a = 1214;
float b = (float)a/(float)1024;

VARIANT c;
VariantInit(&c);
c.fltVal = b;
c.vt = VT_R4;

Comment: @CFCBazarcom You are aware that this question is tagged C#, right, and that the code shown in it is in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I made it.  Please refer to below if you need.

```
UInt32 value = 1075419546;

string hexString = value.ToString("X8");

byte[] floatBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, hexString.Length).Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(x, 2), 16)).ToArray();

Array.Reverse(floatBytes);

float floatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatBytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0:F}", floatValue);
```

Comment: such complex and inefficient code for such a simple operation

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't only post code as an answer, but _also_ provide an explanation about what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Can you [edit] your answer to include this?